# Non-type template inheritance from template linking error

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-specialization

I have an abstract class `DataFormatter` as some interface. I have a derived template `DataFormatterTemplate` for different types of data. Here I have overried pure virtual functions and add specialisation for `Process()` method. Now I want to use data types `INT` that can differ in length. So the idea to use one template with non-type parameters `INT<val>`. I want to use derived from `DataFormatterTemplate` class `DataFormatterTemplatePartial` for my special data types and now I'm trying to override `Process()` method for different `val`, but having undefined reference error.

Whats the problem?

```
template<unsigned val>
struct INT {
    int data[val];
};

/**
 * Data formatter base class
 */
class DataFormatter {
public:
    DataFormatter() {};

    virtual ~DataFormatter() {};

    virtual void Process() = 0;
};

template<class OutFmt>
class DataFormatterTemplate : public DataFormatter {
public:
    virtual ~DataFormatterTemplate() {};

    virtual void Process();
};

template<>
void
DataFormatterTemplate<int>::Process() {}

template<unsigned filNum>
class DataFormatterTemplatePartial : public DataFormatterTemplate<INT<filNum>> {
public :
    virtual void Process();
};

template<unsigned filNum>
void DataFormatterTemplatePartial<filNum>::Process() {
    std::cout << filNum << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    DataFormatterTemplatePartial<4> df;
    DataFormatterTemplatePartial<3> df2;

    df.Process(); 
    df2.Process();

    return 0;
}
```

Linking error:

```
CMakeFiles/dft_test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV21DataFormatterTemplateI3INTILj3EEE[_ZTV21DataFormatterTemplateI3INTILj3EEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `DataFormatterTemplate<INT<3u> >::Process()'

CMakeFiles/dft_test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV21DataFormatterTemplateI3INTILj4EEE[_ZTV21DataFormatterTemplateI3INTILj4EEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `DataFormatterTemplate<INT<4u> >::Process()'
```

As you can see linker trying to find `Process()` specialization in base class, but don't want to use derived.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: @drescherjm has probably nailed the problem, but I can't be sure enough to hammer the question shut. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @drescherjm, that is not the solution. Now I can reformulate the problem as "Why linker try to find specialization in `DataFormatterTemplate` class insted of derived `DataFormatterTemplatePartial`? I've editted the question with small example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you haven't used the `Process()` method of `DataFormatterTemplate` you should give it a definition or mark it as pure virtual.

```cpp
template<class OutFmt>
class DataFormatterTemplate : public DataFormatter {
public:
    virtual ~DataFormatterTemplate() {};

    virtual void Process() = 0;  //  <- should be pure virtual function
                                 //  Or virtual void Process() { /* default behavior */ }
};
```

Comment: Pure virtual function does not suit me, but the default implementation is what was missing!! Thanks!